# How to always count all overlapping substrings in a character string?

Tags: string, count, sas

I have a character string variable that represents subject’s mood over time as 1,2 or 3. As an example, it could look like this:

| Subject | Mood |
| --- | --- |
| Albert | 112132 |
| Betty | 111213 |

I need to understand in how many measures they changed vs stayed static, and how.

My first attempt was to count substrings, e.g.:

STATIC_11 = count(mood,”11”);

However, this did not work (as cautioned by the count function documentation), since “If two occurrences of the specified substring overlap in the string, inconsistent results will be returned.”

In Betty’s case, for instance, I would like her static_11 to always = 2, since the initial string of “111” in mood represents 2 times her mood was 1 following a previous mood of 1.

Mood is a character variable with a non-blank length of 1-9. I really don’t want to have to manually identify all possible substrings myself, though I guess that’s technically a solution.

Comment: If those two rows are the input, what is the fully expected output results?

Answer (score 1):

You can output each adjacent measures state and tabulate them.

```
data have; input
id mood $6.; datalines;
 1 112132
 2 111213
 3 333333
 4 221133
 5 111111
;

data measures;
  set have;
  length measures $2;
  do ix = 2 to length(mood);
    measures = substr(mood,ix-1,2);
    output;
  end;
  drop ix ;
run;

proc tabulate data=measures;
  class id mood measures;
  table id*mood, measures * N='';
run;
```

[image]

Restate your question if you want to evaluate mood states with run-length, or temporal shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun one more solution

Data:

```
data have; 
input id mood $20.; 
datalines;
 1 1121321231
 2 111213332
 3 333
 4 221133
 5 111111223
;
run;
```

Code:

```
filename f "!SASROOT/*.cfg"; /* just some fake reference */
data have;
  set have; 
  infile f truncover;
  input @1 @;
  _infile_ = mood;
  input @1 (m1-m200) ($2. +(-1)) @@;
    
  array mm m1-m200;
  do over mm;
    col1 = mm;
    if length(col1)=2 then output;
                      else leave;
  end;
  keep id mood col1; 
run;
filename f clear;

proc freq data=have;
  table id * col1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to loop over the length of the string using a do loop, starting at 2 and compare each character with the previous one using substr() to extract substrings.

In full this code does:

- Sets up counter variables to store the change vs static counts
- Sets up a two-dimensional array of possible score changes with named variables
- Loops over the mood string character-by-character, converting the values to numeric (using input), so they can be used as array indexes to fill the array
- Increments the static and change counters by comparing the current and previous values

```
data want;
input Subject $ Mood : $32.;
moodlength = length(mood);
/* Set up variables to count score changes */
mood_change = 0;
mood_static = 0;
array changes (3,3) static_11 change_12 change_13 
                    change_21 static_22 change_23 
                    change_31 change_32 static_33;

/* Empty the changes array for the next row */
do i = 1 to 3; do j = 1 to 3; changes(i,j)=0; end;end;

do i = 2 to length(mood);
  prev_mood = input(substr(mood,i-1,1),1.);
  curr_mood = input(substr(mood,i,1),1.);

  /* Increment the counter for the specified score change */
  changes(prev_mood,curr_mood)+1;

  /* Check the previous mood with current and count change vs static */
  if substr(mood,i-1,1) = substr(mood,i,1) then mood_static+1;
  else mood_change+1;

end;

/* Remove temporary variables */
drop i j prev_mood curr_mood;

/* Play with sample data here or use a set statement for an input dataset */
datalines;
Albert 112132132313131311231
Betty 1113
;
proc print;
run;
```